# How can I keep the last animation frame with blit = True

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation, blit

I have to set blit = true, since the plotting is much faster. But after animation (repeat = false), if I use zoom in the figure, the figure will just disappear. I need to keep the last frame so that I can zoom in the last figure.

Comment: I'm currently not sure about the reason, but I filed [an issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12528) for this not to be forgotten.

Comment: Thanks! I am thinking some tricks to "get around" this issue, like plotting only the last frame again, after the animation finishes.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and as a workaround I modified the frames generator that is passed to FuncAnimation to keep yielding the last element infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

One work around is to initialize the animation using the last frame.  The obvious down side is you have to precompute the last frame.  Adapting [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/simple_anim.html) would be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

cnt = 50 # Define so we know what the last frame will be.

def init():
    # Note the function is the same as `animate` with `i` set to the last value
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + cnt / 100))
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x + i / 100))  # update the data.
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, init_func=init, interval=2, blit=True, save_count=cnt)

ani.save("mwe.mov")
fig.savefig("mwe.png")
```